# Cannot get I.swipeLeft() or I.swipeRight() working in CodeceptJS with Appium

Tags: testing, appium, codeceptjs

I'm testing a native Android app and would like to be able to swipe left or swipe right on an element. I have read the documentation here:

https://codecept.io/helpers/Appium.html#swiperight

```
let locator = "#io.selendroid.testapp:id/LinearLayout1";
I.swipeRight(locator); // simple swipe
I.swipeRight(locator, 500); // set speed
I.swipeRight(locator, 1200, 1000); // set offset and speed
```

I can't get it working though. I'm pretty sure I have the right locator as when I do an `I.tap(locator)`, it works.

Has anyone managed to get `I.swipeRight(locator)` or `I.swipeLeft(localtor)` working?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. I'm doing this on iOS instead of Android but what ended up working for me was

```
I.executeScript('mobile: swipe', {direction: 'left'})
```

For other options—which may be platform-specific—you'll probably want to look at Appium docs (not specific to CodeceptJS).